# error : expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant while declaring colorbutton in gtk+

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I want to put some color with gtkButton in GTK+ program, but it shows some declaration error as i've specified above. This is the declaration, i've used in the gtk program.

```
static GdkColor  colorRed;//error line 1
gdk_color_parse("red", &colorRed); //error line 2

button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button");
gtk_widget_modify_base (button1, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &colorRed);
```

but it's displaying error

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant  //line 1
error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token        //line 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration to color the button was correct but i had declared it as global i.e outside the main() function to use the color in multiple function. So, when i put the declaration in side the main() function and replace gtk_widget_modify_base() to gtk_widget_modify_bg() then it's working perfectly.

Here is corrected code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
static void destroy (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data);
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *table;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *button1[20][20];
GtkWidget *button2;
GtkWidget *button3;
GtkWidget *title;
GtkWidget *label;
static char *values[100] = 
{  "127.0.0.1",    "Idle",
 "192.168.73.129", "Idle", 
 "192.168.73.130", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.131", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.132", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.133", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.134", "Idle",
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);  //gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 550, 700);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Client Activity Monitor");
gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 25);
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
table = gtk_table_new(4, 2, TRUE);
gtk_table_set_row_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table), 2);
gtk_table_set_col_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table), 2);

GdkColor  colorRed;//color declaration
gdk_color_parse("red", &colorRed);//color assignment

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int pos = 0;

title = gtk_frame_new("Client Logs");
label = gtk_label_new("server: waiting for connections...\n");
gtk_frame_set_shadow_type(GTK_FRAME(title), GTK_SHADOW_IN);
gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), title, 0, 1, 0, 1);
button3 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Start Server");
gtk_widget_modify_fg(button3, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &colorRed);//color use
gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), button3, 1, 2, 0, 1);

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (title), label);
gtk_widget_show_all(title);

for(i=0; i < 6; i++) {
for( j=0; j < 2; j++) {
  button1[i][j] = gtk_button_new_with_label(values[pos]);
  gtk_widget_modify_fg(button1[i][j], GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &colorRed);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), button1[i][j], j, j+1, i+1, i+1+1 );
  pos++;
}
}
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);
g_signal_connect_swapped (G_OBJECT (button3), "clicked",G_CALLBACK (destroy),(gpointer) window);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();
return 0;
}
static void destroy (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data)
{
gtk_main_quit ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`gtk_widget_modify_base` has been deprecated since 3.0. Use `gtk_widget_override_background_color` instead. You won't need `GdkColor`, just `GdkRGBA`, which is more convenient for cairo anyway.

About your error: I think you're focusing on the wrong part. You snippet is here the compiler sees the error, but lines before are always welcome, and I think your problem is that you're not including the headers for `GdkColor`.